# Packaging a Library for AMD/Require.js With Dependencies

Tags: requirejs, amd

I thought I'd be able to expose my JS library to Require.js, and make it dependent on jQuery, Backbone, and Underscore, with the following code:

```
 } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {

  define(['backbone', 'jquery', 'underscore'], function(Backbone, $, _) {
      return factory(root, Backbone, $, _);
  });
```

where `factory` is a function that returns my library.  That seems ok, except that the module name "backbone" appears to be hard-coded to the filesystem path "{Require root}/backbone".  Even if I define a path in my Require config before requiring the library:

```
'backbone': '/some/other/path/backbone'
```

my browser still gives me an error:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/js/backbone.js 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

Can anyone explain how I can define "this library depends on Backbone" without saying "this library requires exactly {root}/backbone.js"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is [exactly what Backbone does](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html) so I'm not sure why you're having problems. Can you post the code of how you're requiring this library and where you're defining your require config?

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
  define(['underscore', 'jquery', 'exports'], function(_, $, exports) {
```

Comment: I had a typo in my require statement. Thanks for the sanity check.