# External dependencies in public AMD–conforming package

Tags: amd, external-dependencies

I'm developing an open source JavaScript app that depends on an open source JavaScript library.

I'm structuring my app as an AMD package.

I read the [AMD spec](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/blob/master/AMD.md).

I read most of the [RequireJS API](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html) doc.

I feel that I have enough comprehension of the subject.

Although, I'm missing at least one piece.

How should my app expect to receive its dependency?

Is it via an argument in each of the calls that my app exposes, like:

```js
// myApp.js
define(function () {
    return function (Lib, foo) {
        return foo * Lib(2);
    }
});
```

Or, should it be a via a dependency, like:

```js
// myApp.js
define(['Lib'], function (Lib) {
    return function (foo) {
        return foo * Lib(2);
    }
});
```

Or, am I missing something?

It seems like the former, according to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22521520/packaging-a-library-for-amd-require-js-with-dependencies) and its answer.

I'm reading up on [Universal Module Definition](https://github.com/umdjs/umd).